# Как читать весь файл CSV а не только первую строку ? язык PHP

Tags: php, csv

```
$file = fopen($targetFile, 'r');
while(($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Таким способом у меня виводится только первая строка

Comment: Что такое `$bigArr`? И зачем вы используете `exit`? вы понимаете его назначение?

Comment: извините, это из за моего неправильного (copy-paste) - a, уже поправил

Comment: Я использовал exit() для остановки кода после этого... но но подразумывал, что все это в цикле, смешно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите `exit()`. Рекомендую прочитать про эту функцию побольше здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exit.php

Comment: даааа..........